# best approach to design a REST API in Java

Tags: java, rest, api

I'm used to design APIs using SOAP based Web Services using JAX-WS, but I need to switch to REST services.

I wonder what the approach should be:

- start with writing java method signatures
- start writing some sort of WSDL describing the calls even if it won't be used
- start writing some other kind (which one?) of text based description for the API
- use some tools (which one?)
- something else?

I'm not asking about full details, but rather what a REST newbie should think about before to design a REST API before starting writing code. (like too many do)

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Stop thinking about an API as a set of method calls. REST is based on the principles which work on the web - resources and links between them.  Start by considering what resources and what representations of those resources are required.

Comment: thanks. I guess it's a completely different way to consider the API. What about if it's not about accessing resources, but rather performing actions? (and not necessarily on a resource)

Comment: REST is an architectural style for applications operating on resources. If your operations are not on resources (things identified via a web URL) then REST is not a appropriate style to use. You can perform actions either using HTTP methods as verbs, or by creating another resource which is the result of the action and navigating to that resource. As such a navigation is not side effect free, you should use POST rather than GET for the navigation.